# MongoDB: Hash an _id to an integer?

Tags: mongodb, hash

Working with a large collection in mongoDB, it's often helpful to conduct analysis on a sample of documents instead of the whole set.  One clean way to do this would be to run the ObjectIds through a hash function mapping them onto integers, and then use $mod to select a subsample of the documents.

The main point is to draw a sample of documents in a way that is effectively random: selection into the set isn't correlated with anything else we might care about.

Is there a good way to do this?  Bonus points if the query is fast.

PS: I'm aware of the [random attribute](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/random-attribute/) approach, but don't like it much because it wastes storage space.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you get all the objectIds of docs in the collection in an array, sort the array, and then select random index locations in that array?

Comment: Yes, but it involves two queries over the whole collection.